# Database design + relationship for Two types of Genres for product

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-structures, computer-science

I need some help with the structure of my db, I have three tables - one is products for basic product information the second is productvariations this is related to products, productvariations can be a CD, DVD or Blu-ray so basically they are types of products to a particular product - an e.g. would be The Matrix is a product which can contain a CD soundtrack, DVD and or Blue-ray.

The next table I'm having problems with is the list of Genres for a particular product type, I have genres which belong to a product e.g action, drama, sci-fi... but for sound track or just music CD's I would have different genre's like e.g Rock, Jazz, Pop etc... At the moment I can output all genres for DVD's and Blu-Rays but I want to only show those particular genres to a specific product that might be for CD Genres or DVD genres or Blu-ray genres

My table information is like this

Product::

```
Schema::create('products', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('keywords');
    $table->string('title', 160);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('slug', 160);            
    $table->date('release_date');                       
    $table->string('clip', 160)->nullable();                        
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

ProductVarations::

```
Schema::create('productvariations', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('product_id');                                           
    $table->string("image", 160)->nullable();
    $table->bigInteger('producttype_id')->unsigned();
    $table->decimal("price", 5, 2);
    $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('discount')->default(0)->unsigned();
    $table->date("sale_start")->nullable();
    $table->date("sale_end")->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

ProductTypse::

```
Schema::create('producttypes', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('slug', 160);
    $table->string('title', 160);
    $table->string('keywords', 160);
    $table->string('description', 160);         
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Genres::

```
Schema::create('genretypes', function(Blueprint $table)
{

    $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();            
    $table->string('slug', 160);
    [**$table->enum('type', array('Music', 'Movies')) Not sure about this approach**];
    $table->string('title', 160);           
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Product_GenereType:: [**Important Lookup Table Join table for products and genres**]

```
Schema::create('product_genretypes', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();           
    $table->bigInteger('genretype_id')->unsigned();
    $table->unique( array('product_id','genretype_id') );                               
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: Looks like you need a producttypes_genretypes x-ref table as well so you can specify which genres relate to which product type. You could do a complicated join from products and genre types thence to producttypes to get the relationship but this might miss some out if any producttypes have no products in them.

Comment: I just thought of something I could have an extra field in producttypes called genretype(Movie, Music) and then in my genretypes table I could add another field called genretype which would be a an enum of Movie, Music that could help in the relationship